# Converting std::vector container into an std::set using std::transform

Tags: c++, c++11

More specifically I have a vector of some struct

```
std::vector<SomeStruct> extensions = getThoseExtensions();
```

where `someStructVariable.extensionName` returns a string.

And I want to create a set of `extensionName`, something like this `std::set<const char*>`.

Process is fairly straightforward when done using some `for` loops but I want to use `std::transform` from `<algorithm>` instead.

---

`std::transform` has four parameters.

**1,2**. First range (to transform first range from and to)

**3**. Second range/inserter  (to transform second range)

**4**. A function

---

This is what I have so far

```
auto lambdaFn = 
    [](SomeStruct x) -> const char* { return x.extensionName; };

 std::transform(availableExtensions.begin(),
                availableExtensions.end(),
                std::inserter(xs, xs.begin()),
                lambdaFn);
```

because there's no "proper context" for `std::back_inserter` in `std::set` I'm using `std::inserter(xs, xs.begin())`.

---

The problem is I'm trying to return stack mem in my lambda function. So how do I get around this problem?

Oddly enough if I remove `return` from the function it works just like I expect it to! But I don't understand why and that strikes fear of future repercussion.

---

EDIT:

I'm using several structs in place of `SomeStruct` like `VkExtensionProperties` defined in `vulkan_core`

```
typedef struct VkExtensionProperties {
    char        extensionName[VK_MAX_EXTENSION_NAME_SIZE];
    uint32_t    specVersion;
} VkExtensionProperties;
```

From [Khronos specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkExtensionProperties.html)

Comment: What "*stack mem*" are you returning? I assume the `SomeStruct` does not own the character string pointed to by `extensionName`, right? What does "*if I remove `return`*" mean? If you remove the `return` keyword, your lambda will have undefined behavior because it will not be returning a value when it claims to return non-void.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. Btw `std::set` has a constructor that takes two iterators to a range of elements to be inserted. You do not need `std::transform`

Comment: not the problem: The name `functionPointer` is a bit misleading. There is no function pointer in your code. `functionPointer` is a lambda

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Still would need a transforming iterator though if OP wants to extract the member of each element.

Comment: Your `SomeStruct` is passed by value to `functionPointer` which could potentially lead to problems. Would have to see the definition of `SomeStruct`.

Comment: @walnut oh right, my fault. Missed that

Comment: @super I'm using several different structs in place of `SomeStruct`, one is [VkExtensionProperties](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkExtensionProperties.html)

Comment: @walnut I assumed that because of this clang warning I was getting from it "Address of stack memory associated with local variable returned". By *remove* `return` I meant actually removing `return` keyword from the lambda function.

Comment: @atis Your question says `extensionName` is a string and your link says it's a `char*`, and you also say you use different struct. So please clarify. Is the type of `extensionName` always `char*` or could it potentially be different things like `std::string` etc?

Comment: @atis Removing the `return` keyword results in undefined behavior and there should have been a warning by clang as well. The warning makes it sound as if `SomeStruct` *does* own the memory that `extensionName` points to. In that case your approach of taking (non-owning) `const char*` as element type of the `set` is probably already in itself broken (in particular if you don't make sure the `std::vector` outlives the `std::set`). See e.g. answer by AlanBirtles for fixing this.

Comment: @atis Others have mentioned the lifetime of the vector - but even if the vector outlives the set, be aware that adding items to a vector is allowed to move the vector to somewhere else in memory, which would invalidate _all_ the `char*`s in the set! Just another reason `std::set<std::string>` is a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably can't create a set of `char *` unless all instances of `extensionName` with the same value point to the same char array (it would store unique pointers instead of unique values). If you use `std::set<std::string>` instead this will both work and only store unique values and solve your variable lifetime problem as `std::string` takes care of copying (or moving) itself for you where necessary:

```
auto lambdaFn = 
    [](const SomeStruct& x) { return std::string(x.extensionName); };
std::set<std::string> xs;
std::transform(availableExtensions.begin(),
                availableExtensions.end(),
                std::inserter(xs, xs.begin()),
                lambdaFn);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you want is with the following lambda

```cpp
auto lambda = [](const SomeStruct& x) -> const char* { return x.extensions.data();};
```

The problem with this is, that you are saving pointers to memory owned by someone else (those strings). When they are destroyed (this seems to be the case at the end of the function), the pointer will be dangling. You can get around this by allocating memory in your lambda and copying the data:

```cpp
auto lambda = [](const SomeStruct & x) -> const char* {
    char* c = new char[x.extensions.length()+1]; 
    std::strcpy(c, x.extensions.data()); 
    return c;
}
```

But then you have to do memory management yourself (i.e. remember to free those `const char*`). And that is a bad idea. You should probably reconsider what you are doing. Why are you using `const char*` here and not `std:: string`?

Please remember that the typical use for `const char*` is to save string literals i C-code, i.e. the code

```cpp
const char* str = "Hello World!";
```

creates a `char` array of sufficient size in the static section of the memory, initializes it with the string (a compile time constant) and then saves a pointer to that in `str`. This is also why this has to be a `const char*` since another pointer refering to an equal string literal may (or may not) point the exactly the same char array and you don't want to enable change there. So don't just use `const char*` because you see strings in C saved in those `const char*` without anyone needing to free them later.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do here.

1. If you own the definition of `SomeStruct`, it is best if you changed that member to `std::string`.
2. Short of that, see if you lambda can take by-ref parameter `const auto& obj`. This will not create a copy and point back to the object the container has. However, I am still afraid of this solution since this smells like bad class design where ownership and lifetime of members is ambiguous.